# replacing the character with the smallest assigned ASCII number with a random character java

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace the character with the smallest assigned ASCII number in a string with a random character generated within a range.

here's the code:

```
 import java.util.*;

public class TestMethod {

Random rn = new Random();
public synchronized void test(String st){
    while(true){
        char c = (char)rn.nextInt(((126-33)+1)+33);
        int min = (int)st.charAt(0);
        int index = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<st.length(); i++){
            if((int)st.charAt(i) < min){
                min = (int)st.charAt(i);
                index = st.indexOf(i);
            }
        }
        String newst = st.substring(0, index) + c + st.substring(index+1, st.length());

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(newst);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //checks if all characters equal to '~'
        ArrayList<String> stArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        stArr.add(newst);
        for(String i : stArr){
            if(i.length()-i.replace("~", "").length() == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get a runtime error :

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at TestMethod.test(TestMethod.java:18)
at classA.run(classA.java:16)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

at this line :

```
String newst = st.substring(0, index) + c + st.substring(index+1, st.length());
```

what is it that i'm doing wrong ? i've just started experimenting with synchronized.

Comment: Your mistake in finding smallest index. replace  index = st.indexOf(i); -> index = i;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
index = st.indexOf(i);
```

should be

```
index = i;
```